# JavaScript function in a object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand JavaScript functions.
just wanted to know how the value of `console.log(go());` returns 6?

```
var x = 10;
var foo = {
    x: 2,
    baz: {
        x : 1,
        bar: function() {
            return this.x + 1;
        }
    }
}    
var go = foo.baz.bar    
console.log(go()); //returns 6
console.log(foo.baz.bar()); //returns 2
```

can anyone pleas explain me how its returning 6?

Comment: In my browser the `go()` returns `NaN`. In what environment are you testing?

Comment: you have not assign the value to **x** which is first time **undefined** so it will return **NaN not 6**. can you please verify again.

Comment: this will return 6 only you have a context where x has value equal with 5,in your example you should have somewhere defined a global variable x = 5

Comment: sorry guys, it returns **NaN** for me also. may be it was cache issue earlier. if i assign some value to x in the top, for ex: var x = 10, now it returns '11', in the case of  'console.log(foo.baz.bar());' it returns - **2**, how is it happening?

Comment: @IamSarav In the first case (`go()`) `this` refers to the Window, so it's using the global variable `x` thats defined. In the second case (`foo.baz.bar()`) it's referring to `x` in the scope of `foo.baz`. That's why it's giving two different values.

Comment: Got it! thanks for the reply @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: @IamSarav No problem. I think you mean `var x = 5;` rather than `var x = 10;` in your question by the way.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yes, earlier i tried with 'var x = 5' and removed the same, but still browser console was giving me the result *6*.

Comment: one quick quest, why is `10 > 9 > 8` this argument returning false?

Comment: @IamSarav It's being parsed left to right (*computers only compare two things at a time*). It gives the result of the first most left `>` first before going on to the second `>`. So think of it like this `(10 > 9) > 8` -> `true > 8` -> `1 > 8` -> `false`.

Comment: okeyyyyy!!!! got it now :) thanks alot for ur time and reply @SpencerWieczorek

Answer (score 3):

*this* in a function of Javascript represents different objects when the function is called in different ways.

When you write foo.baz.bar(), *this* represents the last object in the calling object chain, that is the *baz* object.

However, in the following code, *this* doesn't represent the *baz* object as the final function call is not using the *baz* object. It belongs to the global object.

```
var go = foo.baz.bar
go();
```

Somewhere in your code, x is a global object valued as 5, hence this.x + 1 would return 6.

Answer (score 2):

console.log(foo.baz.bar()); will returns 2 after running the below code:

```
    var foo = {
    x: 2,
    baz: {
        x : 1,
        bar: function() {
            return this.x + 1;
        }
    }
}    
var go = foo.baz.bar    
console.log(foo.baz.bar()); //returns 2
```

But **console.log(go());** is returning **Nan** in Firefox browser.

Comment: i apologies for it, it was cache issue for me earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the context and scope of `this` for both of these function calls. In the first case:

```
var go = foo.baz.bar;
go();
```

We are simply making `go` be the function that `foo.baz.bar` is, although it is **only** that function. You could think of it as just:

```
function() {
    return this.x + 1;
}
```

Because of that `this` is referring to the `Window`, which is using the global variable `x` for `this.x`. Which is `5`, giving the result `6`.

In the second case we are indeed in the scope of `foo.baz` when we are accessing the function:

```
foo.baz.bar()
```

In this case `this.x` refers to `x` defined in `foo.baz` which is `1`, giving the result `2`.